# Gedit with blurry chars

Tags: gedit, blurry

I am using gedit for PHP development but I noticed since a few months that sometimes when I type something, some parts of the text become blurry and only after a click somewhere else or type another letter it comes back to normal. I got used to this problem but I am curious about what can be causing this type of issue. I've tried to reproduce this error on a screenshot but the Ubuntu's screenshot feature removes the focus of the current window, so it "fix" the error on gedit

Do you know what can I do about it?

EDIT:
This problem only occurs in gedit, and nowhere else.

Here comes the picture of the error:

http://i.imm.io/udEc.jpeg

Comment: There's no telling if you can't get a picture of it. Just take one with a cell phone camera.

Comment: Is it possible there is some sort of 3D acceleration being done with the window manager that is having issues?

Comment: I don't know, it only happens with gedit, even chrome with more advanced render does not have any issues. I am waiting for the picture upload finish and then I'll update the post

Comment: you could try getting in touch with the developers, or posting a bug report (details can be found on [the Gedit homapage](http://projects.gnome.org/gedit/))